# Kernel "make module_install" always gives error

Tags: linux, kernel, call, system

Hey guys i am trying to command a custom system call.

I tried every step given on [this website](https://tssurya.wordpress.com/2014/08/19/adding-a-hello-world-system-call-to-linux-kernel-3-16-0/).
But whenever i enter the " make modules_install install " command i always get this error :

```
      INSTALL arch/x86/crypto/aes-x86_64.ko
cp: cannot stat 'arch/x86/crypto/aes-x86_64.ko': No such file or directory
Can't read module
scripts/Makefile.modinst:30: recipe for target 'arch/x86/crypto/aes-x86_64.ko' failed
make[1]: *** [arch/x86/crypto/aes-x86_64.ko] Error 2
Makefile:1077: recipe for target '_modinst_' failed
make: *** [_modinst_] Error 2
```

I searched everywhere but i am unable to find any answer.

Looking forward for a solution.

Comment: What did you do finally?